# Redirecting users to static homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a client that I am building an adult-oriented site for. The site has a static front page basically stating the content, leave or enter stuff, etc. It is a WordPress site.

What I would like to do- If any user was to click a link from outside the site from someplace else on the net that linked to an interior page the user would always be directed to the static front page of the site and then still be directed to the original link after agreeing to enter the site.

I'm not sure this is even possible.

Thank you in advanced for any help.

Comment: If you can read/write cookies in Wordpress then you could determine if the user had seen the frontpage before and then act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a piece of code to every page - for example in PHP - that checks if a cookie called `visited` exists.
If it doesn't, redirect the user to the front page.

```
if($_COOKIE['visited'] != 'visited')
    header('Location: http://frontpage.com/index.php');
```

Then on the front page, make the `Enter` button create and set the `visited` cookie, and redirect to the other front page.

```
setcookie('visited', 'visited');
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://theOtherFrontPage.com/index.php">';
```

Answer (score 0):

On every page of your site put the following condition

```
if(isset($_SESSION["i_agree"]) && $_SESSION["i_agree"]=="true"){
    //show the content of the page
}
else{
    $_SESSION["redirect_to"]=get_permalink();
    wp_redirect( "http://to-static-front-page" );
    exit; 
}
```

On the static front page that asks for user confirmation, when the user clicks on I agree redirect him  to a set_session.php file

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/set_session.php">I agree</a>
```

In set_session.php put the following code

```
<?php
$_SESSION["i_agree"]="true";
if(isset($_SESSION["redirect_to"])){
    $redirect_url=$_SESSION["redirect_to"];
}
else{
    $redirect_url=home_url();//path to your home page
}
wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
exit;
?>
```